# What are the different categories of grammar mistakes

Tags: grammar

I am comparing two editions of an English language book, and making notes of what the changes were between them.

In each case, I need to indicate a reason for the change, but I don't know which word to use to describe that change type in all cases.

1. "have nto" => "have not" = Spelling error
2. "must have" => "must not have" = ?
3. "should have have" => "should have" = ?
4. "And now: I must go" => "And now, I must go" = ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if there are "official" categories for these mistakes or simply asking for suggestions for category names? e.g. logic error, duplication error, punctuation error...

Comment: [A] By "English language book" , I hope you mean a book on some topic written in English, not a book on English grammar, because that book looks like a bad book to learn English from. [B] While (1), (2) & (3) look like mistakes, (4) may not be a mistake, in some cases. [C] There are hundreds & thousands of categories of mistakes but no universal list of categories [D] If you are working on some academic assignment, you should ideally ask the instructor for a list of categories [E] If you are looking for a list of Editing terms, try this https://nybookeditors.com/2013/06/copyediting-marks/ ....

Comment: I've used the word *typo* for all such mistakes.

Comment: @YosefBaskin , Here, the OP requirement is "In each case, I need to indicate **a reason** for the change" , not a blanket term but rather categories of mistakes

Comment: Misspellings (1) and wrong punctuation (4) (though that's a contentious example; 150 years ago, it probably wouldn't have raised an eyebrow – and we still read books from then) are not seen as grammatical errors by academics. Accidentally omitting words, inserting wrong ones when you'd realise your mistake on re-reading, or retyping them, are typos. But there are many aspects of grammar (do a search here) and many ways of getting things wrong on a consistent basis because of ignorance (= being unaware of correct practices).